# How to forward block in alias_method_chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation where I need to use `alias_method_chain`

```
 alias_method_chain :allowed_to?, :update

 def allowed_to_with_update?(action, context, options={}, &block)
   if action.eql?(:update)
     false
    else
      allowed_to_without_update?(action, context, options, &block)
    end
 end
```

It's showing error,

```
stack level too deep
```

on this line,

```
 allowed_to_without_update?(action, context, options, &block)
```

Any idea how can I forward block?

Comment: Can’t check here, but `alias_method_chain` is nothing but a syntactic sugar for concatenating methods, so the question mark would break the pattern. That said, `allowed_to_without_update?` is _not_ a chained method that’s why you yield the “stack level too deep” error.

Would you try `alias allowed_to, allowed_to?` and then `alias_method_chain :allowed_to, :update ...`?